# Store value from input to database

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin

This is the input type I currently have in `index.php`:

```
<fieldset>
      <input type="text" placeholder="GSM" name="gsm" required>
</fieldset>
```

In the `saveToDb.php` I have this:

```
$gsm = $_POST['gsm'];
```

It all works fine, but I want to change from text input to drop down. I have managed to load values into my drop down like this:

```
<?php
    $filename = 'values.txt';
    $eachlines = file($filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);//create an array
    echo '<select name="value" id="value">';
    foreach($eachlines as $lines){
        echo "<option>{$lines}</option>";
        
    }
    echo '</select>';
?>
```

How can I store the values from dropdown to database, insted of of input text?

Comment: `value` should be your friend

Comment: @B001ᛦ Do you mean `echo '<select name="value" id="value">';` should be `echo '<select name="value" id="gsm">';`? It works saving, but the value saved is blank.

Comment: No I mean option value, because you want to store the value of the options ;)

Comment: @B001ᛦ Not sure if I know how to do it correctly? `echo "<option value>{$lines}</option>";` still saves blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign a value on each option:

```
echo '<select name="name-of-the-field" id="value">';
foreach($eachlines as $lines){
    echo "<option value=\"{$lines}\">{$lines}</option>";
}
```

and the value you will receive is the one of the `option` selected (in order to get the value, nothing changes, you still have to use `$selected_value = $_POST['name-of-the-field'];`)

Comment: I get syntax error on line `echo "<option value="{$lines}">{$lines}</option>"`

Comment: `foreach($eachlines as $lines){
    echo "<option value="'.$lines.'">"'.$lines.'"</option>";
}`. try this.

Comment: Missing semicollon (;) on line 3.

Comment: @Curt155 sorry i was missing the semicolon and the `"` were not escaped, now it should work

Comment: @Curt155 in my code there are generic values, names, ids, ecc ecc, you don't have to copy paste and leave it as it is, you have to change those values to met what you want (btw, `id` has nothing to do with servers, is only used on the front end side)

Comment: @Berto99 Sorry I don't understand. What values should I change?

Comment: @Curt155 make sure the "name" attribute of the select element matches the index of the POST array you are trying to access in PHP. The id is not relevant when submitting the form, only the name and value gets sent to the server

Comment: @ADyson exactly